# jQuery form validation using a class for specific fields only

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, oracle-apex

I'm trying to develop a means of telling form fields that they are required fields via a class of "required".

I would like to use jQuery that will highlight all the fields that are required, when the user submits the form and via the jQuery class, show user all the missed/required fields.

Obviously, as the user enters data into the required fields, the jQuery class is removed from these fields.

I am wondering how to approach this requirement, specifically using Oracle Application Express (Oracle ApEx).

Answer (score 1):

There is a really complete jquery plugin for this. It will validate your form depending on the classes you add to your input field:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Check out the demo:
http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/